# Rails where query with or

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

i have the following query in my app:

```
Page.where(published: false).where("published_at > current_date").where("publication_end IS NULL OR publication_end < current_date")
```

Now i want to change this where to or, I was trying:

```
Page.where((published: false) || ("published_at > current_date"))
```

but it not working. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Page.where('published = ? OR published_at > current_date', false)
```